# Chess traps without positional loss

Tags: opening, positional-play, beginner

Most of the common chess traps are ill advised (at least in standard games), as you sacrifice better moves.

Traps that I have tried out with some success are the fishing pole, and the blackbourne shilling gambit. But common for these common trap plays, is that if spotted, I am left in a bad position.

In fishing pole, black often play black bishop and forces me to pin my knight.
In blackbourne gambit, the opponent often simply take the knight rather than the poisoned pawn.

Are there any common chess traps, without a positional loss, that are worth studying?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following traps do not lead to any positional loss for the side setting the trap. It's obviously not an exhaustive list-

**A common trap in the Sicilian**

```
  [FEN ""]

  1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. c3 Nf6 4. Be2 Nxe4?? 5. Qa4+ Bd7 6. Qxe4
```

**Queen's Gambit Elephant Trap**

```
  [FEN ""]
  1. d4. d5 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Nf6 4. Bg5 Nbd7 5. cxd5 exd5 6. Nxd5?? Nxd5 7. Bxd8 Bb4+ 8. Qd2 Kxd8 9. e4 Bxd2+
```

**Trap in the Alapin Sicilian**

```
  [FEN ""]
  1. e4 c5 2. c3 d5 3. exd5 Qxd5 4. d4 e6 5. Nf3 Nc6 6. Bd3 cxd4 7. cxd4 Nxd4?? 8. Nxd4 Qxd4?? 9. Bb5+ Bd7 10. Qxd4
```

**Cambridge Springs Trap**

```
  [FEN ""]
  1.d4 d5 2.c4 e6 3.Nc3 Nf6 4.Bg5 Nbd7 5.e3 c6 6.Nf3 Qa5 7. Bd3?! dxc4 8. Bxc4 Ne4 9. Qc2?? Nxg5 10. Nxg5 Qxg5
```

**Trap in Sveshnikov Sicilian**

```
  [FEN ""]
  1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 e5 6. Ndb5 d6 7. Nd5 Nxd5 8. exd5 Ne7 9. c4 a6? 10. Qa4 axb5 11. Qxa8 (10...Qd7 11. Nxd6+)
```

**Trap in the Philidor defense**

```
  [FEN ""]

    1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 Nd7 4. Bc4 Be7? (4... Ngf6? 5. dxe5 Nxe5 6. Nxe5 dxe5 7.
    Bxf7+ Kxf7 8. Qxd8 Bb4+ 9. Qd2 Bxd2+ 10. Nxd2) 5. dxe5! dxe5?? (5... Nxe5 6. Nxe5
    dxe5 7. Qh5 g6 8. Qxe5) 6. Qd5 Nh6 (6...Nf6?? 7.Qxf7#) 7. Bxh6 O-O 8. Be3
```

**Ruy Lopez Noah's Ark Trap**

```
   [FEN ""]

    1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bb5 a6 4. Ba4 b5 (4... d6 5. d4 b5 6. Bb3 Nxd4 7. Nxd4
    exd4 8. Qxd4?? c5) 5. Bb3 d6 6. d4 Nxd4 7. Nxd4 exd4 8. Qxd4?? c5 9. Qd5 Be6 10.          
    Qc6+ Bd7 11. Qd5 c4
```

**Siberian Trap in the Smith-Morra Gambit**

```
    [FEN ""]

    1. e4 c5 2. d4 cxd4 3. c3 dxc3 4. Nxc3 Nc6 5. Nf3 e6 6. Bc4 Qc7 7. O-O Nf6 8.
    Qe2 Ng4 9. h3?? Nd4! 10. Nxd4 (10. hxg4 Nxe2+) (10. Qd1 Nxf3+ 11. Qxf3 Qh2#) 10...
    Qh2# 0-1
```

**Trap in the Rauzer Sicilian**

```
    [FEN ""]

    1. e4 c5 2. Nf3 d6 3. d4 cxd4 4. Nxd4 Nf6 5. Nc3 Nc6 6. Bg5 e6 7. Qd2 a6 8. f4
    h6 9. Bh4? Nxe4! 10. Nxe4 (10. Bxd8 Nxd2 11. Nxc6 bxc6 12. Bc7 Nxf1) 10... Qxh4+
    11. g3 Qd8
```

Comment: Nice list, but in the first diagram doesn't black equalize with some normal move say `4...g6` or `4...e6`?

Comment: excellent answer Wes. I would just add Albin Counter gambit trap.

Comment: @Akavall, it's not static equality. It is dynamic equality, which Black eventually achieves in all other lines of the Sicilian. There is much to play for in that position, so White is not at a "positional" loss in any way. Notable game - Svidler vs Kasparov 1-0 http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1070948

Comment: @SalvadorDali I'm deliberately avoided mentioning the Lasker trap in the Albin CounterGambit, because I don't think the Albin CounterGambit is a sound opening for Black.

Comment: @Wes, I am not sure that main-lines of the Sicilian lead to dynamic equality, but even if they do I am sure it is much harder to achieve it than in the above line. If you look at the comments in your link, they are pretty dismissive of the line, where Svidler's main objective was to avoid Kasparov's preparation.

Comment: @Akavall, I don't quite agree with the comments that are dismissive of the line. There are other games as well where strong Grandmasters have used this line successfully. For e.g.
http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1018822
http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1452554
http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1545522

The line is double edged, but positionally quite playable for White. Kasparov played it 8 times himself, although only in simultaneous exhibitions.

Comment: @Wes, I looked at the line more myself, and seems that it is reasonably popular, so maybe I wrong in saying "black equalize with some normal move". I personally like these types of strategies against the Sicilian, so I am glad that white has this option :).

Comment: @wes there are some > 2500 rated players who plays Counter-Albin, among whom is Alexand Morozevich with 2700+ who is currently like 30-th in the world. So I think it might qualify as sound. On the other hand it is hard to find a high level player playing Phillidor defense.

Comment: @SalvadorDali, there are many lines (not as many openings) top players play which other Grandmasters consider to be unsound. So you are free to hold that the Albin CounterGambit is sound. I don't want to be the one recommending it as a sound opening it, so I didn't post it. For the Philidor defense, I'm recommending the line as White and not as Black.

Comment: @SalvadorDali One example is the Budapest Gambit. I avoided mentioning the traps in that opening even though it has been played by very strong players (ELO 2700+) because I don't believe the Budapest Gambit is a sound opening.

Answer (score 3):

Seeing excellent answer by Wes, I would like to add Albin Counter Gambit trap. Albin Counter Gambit is played on the highest level of chess.

```
[FEN ""]
1. d4 d5
2. c4 e5 3. dxe5 d4 4. e3? Bb4+ 5. Bd2 dxe3 6. Bxb4?? exf2+ 7. Ke2 fxg1=N+!
```

Information about a trap can be [found here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albin_Countergambit,_Lasker_Trap). The trap is interesting also because it allows one of the fastest possible underpromotion (to a knight).

Comment: Just add a `[FEN ""]` line before the move list to turn it into a fancy diagram. You can click the *edit* link on other posts to see the markdown which produced them.